# Unsure why I am getting: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to do a simple test but am experiencing errors. I am trying to add the parameters and I have done some research, none of which has helped me understand where I have gone wrong.

I have already tried looking on the PHP website and Stackoverflow. This is for a test project.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT username, rank, id, steamid, avatar FROM users WHERE id="$uid"');

$stmt->bind_param('i', $uid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $rank, $id, $steamid, $avatar);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

My expected result is for it to select only the rows specified with the "WHERE" call. My actual result is this error:

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are binding one variable, but you have zero parameters in your prepared statement. Interpolating a PHP variable into a string is *not* a parameter.

WRONG: Zero parameters, just string interpolation:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT username, rank, id, steamid, avatar FROM users 
  WHERE id="$uid"');
```

RIGHT: One parameter:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT username, rank, id, steamid, avatar FROM users
  WHERE id=?');
```

Answer (score 0):

You get error because you don't use `column name = ?` in the prepared statement. Then using `bind_param` you bind values to parameters, set  parameters and execute.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT username, rank, id, steamid, avatar FROM users WHERE id = ?');

$stmt->bind_param('i', $uid);
//set parameters and execute
$uid = 'value here';
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: You should also [add a description to your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/979052), as explaining what it does will help OP and others learn.

Comment: @Lissy93 description added.